# Is it possible to make grand parent child query

Tags: elasticsearch

i have some relational data and i need to establish the connection between data along one level using parent child query. But then i need to establish 2 level relation as in parent child query. Is it possible using Elasticsearch and if possible what is the performance overhead of such queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , its possible. 
You need to use parent child query in a nested fashion.
But be warned that this could be very memory intensive as all the lucene documents for the children documents needs to be loaded for grandchildren query.

```
POST /company/country/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "branch",
      "query": {
        "has_child": {
          "type": "employee",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "hobby": "hiking"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more information [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/grandparents.html)